# Unable to build with electron-packager within electron-forge

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, electron-packager, electron-forge

I have created a default project with electron-forge. When I try to package my project with the command `electron-forge`, the process exits with the following error.

What am I doing wrong? I followed the instructions to a tee at [electron-forge](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge#usage).

```
$ electron-forge package
✔ Checking your system
✔ Preparing to Package Application for arch: x64
✔ Compiling Application
✔ Preparing native dependencies
⠦ Packaging Application
An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Command failed: npm prune --production
npm WARN electron-example@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! May not delete: /tmp/electron-packager/linux-x64/electron-example-linux-x64/resources/app/node_modules/.bin

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/maxchehab/.npm/_logs/2017-07-21T04_40_37_618Z-debug.log

Error: Command failed: npm prune --production
npm WARN electron-example@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! May not delete: /tmp/electron-packager/linux-x64/electron-example-linux-x64/resources/app/node_modules/.bin

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/maxchehab/.npm/_logs/2017-07-21T04_40_37_618Z-debug.log

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:270:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:921:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved in later versions of npm, please consider upgrading to the latest v ( > `5.4.2`) instead of downgrading to `5.2`:

```
npm i -g npm
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the latest version of npm has introduced a bug for the electron make process. Issue is being tracked here.
[Github Issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17781)

Try this workaround for a possible fix(untested):

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install --production --ignore-scripts
npm install --no-save electron-rebuild --ignore-scripts
node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild
npm remove electron-rebuild --ignore-scripts
```

Or downgrade your npm to a version less than 5.3(tested, works).

```
npm i -g npm@5.2
```

Comment: Fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped you.