# ElectronJS npm start / bash: electron-forge: command not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, electron, electron-forge

**My System:**

- Mac OSX 10.14.6
- Electron: 10.1.5
- electron-forge: ^6.0.0-beta.54

I've been working on an Electron side project. I started it using electron-forge, I had a small application functioning just fine, I then set it aside for a couple weeks. Coming back to it, I tried running `npm start` and it did nothing but return to a new terminal line. So I tried `electron-forge start` and it returned `bash: electron-forge: command not found`.

I tried deleting my `node_modules` folder and reinstalling, I tried creating a new electron-forge boilerplate, and neither made a difference. I tried installing electron-forge globally, but it errored out on the second step, and I found several stackoverflow articles saying I shouldn't have electron-forge installed globally. I haven't changed anything (that I know of) on a system level, but it seems to be a system issue, rather than a package issue, but I'm not knowledgable enough to do anything other than Google the errors and see what stacksoverflow articles are out there, but no articles have helped.

I'd love any and all help, Electron has ceased working on my system completely, and I have no idea how to troubleshoot it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to build with electron-packager within electron-forge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45229218/unable-to-build-with-electron-packager-within-electron-forge)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up deleting and re-installing Node and that seems to have fixed it. Still not sure what caused the initial issue, but it's working again. For those interested, here's the resources I used:

- https://stackabuse.com/how-to-uninstall-node-js-from-mac-osx/
- https://pawelgrzybek.com/install-nodejs-installer-vs-homebrew-vs-nvm/

**Update:**

I kept having issues running `npm start`. What finally worked was to create a new boilerplate project using the CLI and copy the contents of the `package-lock.json` to the old project. That finally launched the app.

Comment: I had the same issue, even after I uninstalled and reinstalled Node. What I eventually tried was to delete `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` again. After that I was able to start my application.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command below

```
npm install electron
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but, I had the same issue and instead of uninstalling Node, I used `rm -rf node_modules` then I used `npm cache clean --force`. I reinstalled my dependencies and electron-forge worked again.